# MVC ASP.net definition GetEnumerator error

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, view

So i get the error message in the title and i dont understand why.

Heres how i reference the model in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<Lowflix.Models.LendingIndexModel>
```

The errors coming up in this foreach

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
```

Really cant explain to myself how this i get this error since i even declared IEnumerable. It contains multiple objects.

This is the error message:

```
foreach statemetn cannot operate on variables
of type "Models" because "Models" does not 
contain  a public instance of GetEnumerator
```

-
model:

```
using Lowflix.Core.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Lowflix.Models
{
    public class LendingIndexModel
    {
        public LendingIndexModel()
        {
        }
        public Guid LendingId { get; set; }
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Guid CopyId { get; set; }

        public String Title { get; set; }


        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReturnDate { get; set; }


        public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public virtual Copy Copy { get; set; }

}
```

debugging model:
model type:

```
    +       Model   {System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator
<Lowflix.Core.Entities.Lending,
 Lowflix.Models.LendingIndexModel>} System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
<Lowflix.Models.LendingIndexModel> 

{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator
<Lowflix.Core.Entities.Lending, 
Lowflix.Models.LendingIndexModel>}
```

Comment: What type exactly the `Model` currently has? It is possible that `Model` property contains a class or type which not implements collection interface.

Comment: i've added the model into the question

Comment: The model class seem looking fine, also with `@model IEnumerable<Lowflix.Models.LendingIndexModel>` directive. What I want to clarify is actual type of `Model` property contains before using `foreach (var item in Model)` loop which throwing exception (put a breakpoint to see it).

Comment: i did debug it and model found the model type. added it into question.

Comment: What does the action in your controller look like?

Comment: return View(model.toList());

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code.

```
@model List<Lowflix.Models.LendingIndexModel>
```

In the View page change IEnumerable to List.